# ClassNotFoundException DynamiteModuleInitializer Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Since i updated my android studio and sdk. these errors started occurring at once and preventing me from writing to the a child in the database, i have no idea what the problem is. but it seems that when i'm trying to write to the database from the "EditCarPostActivity" activity it is occurring, From other activities i can write and update and retrieve information perfectly. Please help with this problem. I will post some activities below

Error 1

> 04-29 18:38:54.685 11007-11034/com.example.ahmad.carrental E/ChimeraFileApk: Failed to validate DexClassLoader.
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.chimera.DynamiteModuleInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

Error 2

> 04-29 18:38:54.686 11007-11034/com.example.ahmad.carrental E/ChimeraModuleLdr: Failed to load code for module FileApk(/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk)
>       ddp: Failed to load code for /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk

Error 3

> 04-29 18:38:54.686 11007-11034/com.example.ahmad.carrental W/ChimeraDebugLogger: Singleton logger instance not set.
>   04-29 18:38:54.686 11007-11034/com.example.ahmad.carrental E/DynamiteLoaderV2: Failed to create module context.
>       ddp: Failed to load code for /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002d/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk

**EditCarPostActivity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_car_post);

    initialization();
    setupFirebaseAuth();
    setUpLocationSpinner();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    //Assigning Car object with its data from database.
    Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter emitter) throws Exception {
            singleValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    car = mFirebaseUtilities.getCarByUserID(userID,dataSnapshot);
                    editCarPostPresenter.populateViews(car);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CANCELLED.");
                }
            };
            mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(singleValueEventListener);
        }
    }).unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();

    //Save all the changes when done editing to database.
    checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editCarPostPresenter.onSaveChanges(car);
        }
    });

    //When user click image button, start image selection from gallery
    tvImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INT);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Will listen for user image selection and will store the selected image in a uri object, then call getUriImage to update it
 * When the user finishes editing and clicks the check button along with any change in car information to the database.
 * @param requestCode
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading .....");
        mProgressDialog.show();
        Uri uri  = data.getData();

        storagePathReference = mStorageReference.child("Photos").child(userID).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        //Update all the information with the image given as Uri
        storagePathReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Image Upload success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    downloadImageUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.get().load(downloadImageUri).fit().centerCrop().into(ivCarPicture);
                }
            });
    }
}

public void deleteUnusedImages(Car car){
    car = this.car;
    String imageID = car.getPicture();
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){

    }

}


//initalizing everything necessary here
public void initialization(){
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    editCarPostPresenter = new EditCarPostPresenter(this,this);

    //Adapter set up for spinners
    mArrayAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.car_brands,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    mArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.car_status_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //Status spinner set up
    statusSpinner = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarStatusSpinner_ID);
    statusSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    statusSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    //Brand spinner set up
    brandSpinner = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarBrandSpinner_ID);
    brandSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter2);
    brandSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    layoutContainer = findViewById(R.id.createPostLinearLayout_ID);
    tvDistance = new TextView(this);
    tvDistance.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvDistance.setText("Distance Travelled");
    etDistance = new EditText(this);
    etDistance.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //margin settings editText
    layoutParamsEt = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)etDistance.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsEt.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    etDistance.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsEt);

    //margin settings textView
    layoutParamsTv = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tvDistance.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParamsTv.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    tvDistance.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTv);

    ivCarPicture = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarPic_ID);
    tvImageButton = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarLinkPic_ID);
    etCarLocation = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarLocation_ID);
    etDescription = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarDes_ID);
    etPrice = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarPrice_ID);
    etModel = findViewById(R.id.createPostCarModel_ID);
    checkButton = findViewById(R.id.check_ID);
    mFirebaseUtilities = new FirebaseUtilities(this);
    mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

private void setUpLocationSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> listOfCities = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TR_cities));

    //--- to ensure user is restricted to selections from drop-down menu
    etCarLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            carLoactionStr = etCarLocation.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        }
    });

    etCarLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            for (int i = 0; i < etCarLocation.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                if (etCarLocation.getText().toString().equals(etCarLocation.getAdapter().getItem(i))) {
                    carLoactionStr = etCarLocation.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
                } else
                    carLoactionStr = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    //start autocomplete after 1 letter
    etCarLocation.setThreshold(1);
    etCarLocation.performCompletion();
    etCarLocation.setAdapter(listOfCities);
}

/**
 * Listener for car status spinner and brand spinner
 * @param parent
 * @param view
 * @param position
 * @param id
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)parent;

    if(spinner.getId() == R.id.createPostCarStatusSpinner_ID){
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        carStatusStr = textView.getText().toString();
        addDynamicViews(position);
    }
    else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.createPostCarBrandSpinner_ID){
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        carBrandStr = textView.getText().toString();
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

/**
 * Dynamic views creation done by handling user spinner selection for first hand or second hand car status.
 *@param position: position of selected value from spinner
 */
public void addDynamicViews(int position){
   /*
   * it crashes if you change from first hand to second hand twice at the same time. so dont do it*/
    if(position == 1){
        layoutContainer.addView(tvDistance);
        layoutContainer.addView(etDistance);
    }
    else if(position == 0){
        Log.i(TAG,"entering");
       //mFirebaseUtilities.removeNodeDynamically();
        layoutContainer.removeView(tvDistance);
        layoutContainer.removeView(etDistance);
    }
}

@Override
public void setBrand(String brand) {
    int spinnerPos = mArrayAdapter.getPosition(brand);
    brandSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPos);
}

@Override
public void setPrice(int price) {
    etPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
}

@Override
public void setLocation(String location) {
    etCarLocation.setText(location);
}

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
    etDescription.setText(description);
}

@Override
public void setModel(String model) {
    etModel.setText(model);
}

@Override
public void setDistance(String distance) {
    etDistance.setText(distance);
}

@Override
public void setStatus(String status) {
    int spinnerPos = mArrayAdapter.getPosition(status);
    statusSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPos);
}

@Override
public void setPicture(String picture) {
   Picasso.get().load(picture).fit().centerCrop().into(ivCarPicture);
}

@Override
public String getBrand() {
    return carBrandStr;
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return etDescription.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public String getLocation() {
    return carLoactionStr;
}

@Override
public String getModel() {
    return etModel.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public String getStatus() {
    return carStatusStr;
}

@Override
public String getPicture() {
    return downloadImageUri.toString();
}

@Override
public int getPrice() {
    String priceViewTemp = etPrice.getText().toString();
    if (priceViewTemp.equals("")) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return Integer.valueOf(etPrice.getText().toString());
    }
}

@Override
public String getDistance() {
    String distanceViewTemp = etDistance.getText().toString();
    if (distanceViewTemp.equals("")) {
        return "0";
    } else {
        return etDistance.getText().toString();
    }
}

/*************************************** Firebase *******************************************/
private void setupFirebaseAuth() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                //User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: user signed in : " + user.getUid());
            } else {
                //User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: user signed out");
            }
        }
    };

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (singleValueEventListener != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(singleValueEventListener);
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(singleValueEventListener);
}
```

}

If you need more information you can ask. And yes my firebase auth is enabled as well as storage and realtime database

Comment: What sort of device are you running this on?

Comment: Android 7.0 Huawei mate 10 lite

Comment: It looks to me like there is a problem with Play services on it.  Try an emulator that has the Play store on it instead.

Comment: But how can i fix that problem. An emulator always crashes on my pc, i tried another device it didnt work. i need to identify the problem and fix it

Comment: You might be better off contacting Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @Akay did you ever found a solution? I'm having the same issue. Did you also update to the 3.1.1?

Comment: We are experiencing the same crash when GoogleCast is initialized. It occurs on numerous HUAWEI devices and none other...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on my Huawei device (a P9 Lite with android 7.0), to solve this issue just remove the currently installed version of Google Play Services restoring it to the default one that shipped with our device (this can be done via the settings app). 
Then reboot your device, and update the Google Play Services application to the latest version. Then run your application and it should work.

Comment: I did the inverse of this answer, just by updating Google Play Services to latest version and it worked.

Comment: There wasn't a new version of google play services available (at least in my region) when i wrote the reply :) so i proceeded with this workaround, as you stated updating to the new version of google play services that is now available also solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem with on my Huawei device (a P9 Lite with android 7.0), i have solved this by **Clear Cache** inside the **Settings-->Apps-->Google Play Services-->Storage**

I hope this will help you.
Cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Honor STF-L09. I resolved the issue by updating the google play services to the beta version, as there are known problems with the current version on huawei and honor devices.

See below for instructions:
https://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-services-huawei-honor-866884/

It gives a bit more insight, but basically it contains a link to sign up for the google play services beta:

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.gms